# Ionic 5 lab does not show windows phone platform

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

I am relatively new to ionic and I am using the ionic lab to have an overview for every device(ios, android, windows). It works fine with android, ios, and the web app so far. But when I choose to see the windows platform I get a black page with the following errors

Error:

> Cannot find module './undefined.entry.js
>   Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'isProxied' of undefined ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'isProxied' of undefined

Comment: Did you use in array show like result?.imagepath ? Since this '?' Can lead to such error behaivior on windows.

Comment: No, I did not. Even with a simple app, if I just follow the documentation from the ionic official page, everything works fine except the windows platform. If I unchecked the windows platform the error goes away. Is there some extra package I have to install in order for this to work?

Comment: if you did a nirmal ionic serve will give the same error? Or wait.. do you mean windows phone or the browser?

Comment: ionic serve works fine, also ionic lab works fine too. The problem is only with the windows phone platform.